# Creating a flag swimlane chart in D3.js

Tags: d3.js

[image: flag activity chart]

Is there a way in D3.js to create the shown chart to represent activity (on/off) of a set of flags?  The data feeding it would look something like:

```
datetime,flag1,flag2,flag3,flag4,none
6/29/2015 06:45:36,1,0,0,1,0
6/29/2015 06:47:05,1,1,0,1,0
6/29/2015 07:20:22,1,1,0,0,0
6/29/2015 07:20:46,0,1,1,0,0
6/29/2015 07:20:59,0,0,0,0,1
```

I am hoping to have something where the x-axis scales time appropriately (which my representation does not do).  It is assumed that the flag stays in the same state between successive records.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "Swimlane Chart" displays activity lanes with indicators of activity.

Example: [D3.js Swimlane Chart](http://bl.ocks.org/bunkat/1962173)